# C# - Changing Window Address when making an AJAX Call

Tags: c#, ajax, window.location

I have a C# page that checks that a user is logged in when making ajax calls and regular calls. I run the following check after determining the user is not logged in:

```
base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
  return Content("<script type='text/javascript'> window.location = '/login' </script>");
}
else
{
  filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Login/?referURL=" + filterContext.HttpContext.Server.UrlEncode(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery));
}
```

The problem I am running into is in the 'if' part. I get an error saying that the name 'Content' does not exist. I need a way to redirect my window location to '/login'.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning plain text return Json data and grab your redirect url from there and  set redirect on Ajax success.

```
 var data = new { IsSucess = true, 
                  redirectUrl = Url.Action("Action", "Controller")}

filterContext.Result = new JsonResult() { data  , 
                       JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
```

Then use JsonResult data like this in your Ajax call,

```
success: function (data) {
                if (data.IsSucess)
                    window.location = data.redirectUrl;
```

Comment: Putting this in I get errors on IsSuccess and redirectUrl saying it doesn't contain a definition and on Url I get an error saying it does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Url still doesn't exist in the current context and there is an error for data saying that invalid initializer member declarator.